# Power series and intervals of convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

While teaching power series in my AP Calculus class, an interesting question came up.  I gave an answer that I believe is correct, but I'm not certain why it is correct except "by definition", but I feel like it's a cop-out to say "since it's an **interval** of convergence it must be an interval" (after all, there is the case where the interval of convergence is just a set with a single element). 
The question was this:

Does the interval of convergence of a power series (of real variables) have to be an interval, or can it be the union of disjoint intervals?  It seems to me that, because the interval is normally found using the geometric series definition or the ratio test, both of which involve solving a less-than inequality of x, that the interval has to be just that, an interval (or just a set with cardinality 1, containing the center of the series only).  Any insight you can give me into this (such as counter-examples or a better explanation) would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Once a power series $\sum_na_n(x-a)^n$ converges absolutely for $x=a+b$ it must converge for all $a+c$ with $|c|<|b|$. Once the general term $|a_n||x-a|^n$ doesn't tend to zero for an $x=a+b$ then it doesn't tend to zero for all $x=a+c$ for $|c|>|b|$. Therefore, the points where it converges absolutely form an interval centered at $a$, the points in which the general term doesn't tend to zero form the complement of an interval centered at $a$. And by comparing with a geometric series you can compute that those intervals are the same.

Comment: Why not teach them the Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula ? The proof, restricted to $\Bbb R,$ is verbatim the same as the proof in $\Bbb C$ and is not long or hard.

Comment: This is a high school advanced placement calculus course.  As much as I try to input theory into the class, I'm limited by both time and the College Board's curriculum, which is mostly mechanical and application in nature (but that's true of almost all intro-level calculus courses in college)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n$.

The proof essentially comes down to looking at a geometric series. Indeed, if we rewrite the power series to look like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(a_n^{1/n}(x-a)\right)^n$, we can see that if $a_n^{1/n}\to c$ for some $c\in(0,1)$, then our power series is "similar to" (in a vague sense) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(cx-ac)^n$, which converges precisely for $|cx-ac|<1$. Doing the algebra yields the inequality $a-\frac{1}{c}<x<a+\frac{1}{c}$ which is exactly the same as the interval $(a-\frac1c,a+\frac1c)$. This yields the values of $x$ for which the series converges absolutely. We must take care on the endpoints, but realize that $[a,b)$ and $(a,b]$ are still intervals.

If $a_n^{1/n}\to c>1$, then the series diverges since $(a_n^{1/n}(x-a))^n\approx (c(x-a))^n$ and $x-a$ is constant (as far as the summing index is concerned).

Comment: "converges precisely for $|cx-ax|<1$" and an extra key information: That for $>1$ the general term doesn't tend to zero, which is what gives divergence of the original series without the absolute value. Without that key observation, it happens like in the other answer, you only know that the set of absolute convergence is an interval and not more.

Comment: @yixing: I was in the process of editing my answer, so I did not see your comment.

Comment: Now it is good.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a series of the form

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} c_n x^n$$

(centered at zero, although this isn't important). A comparison test (related to geometric series!) shows that if the series converges at some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then it converges absolutely 
for *all* $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|b| < |a|$. In particular, the set where the series converges is convex - the set contains the entire interval between any two of its elements.

The only convex sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are the intervals.

---

This generalizes nicely to higher dimensions, such as the complex numbers. The same argument with absolute values applies, and we have a nice theorem which says that the domain where a power series converges is a disk (possible together with some of its boundary).

Comment: The conclusion that you can draw is that the from that comparison is that the set where it converges *absolutely* is an interval. Maybe the set where it converges conditionally is weird.

Comment: I know I can. Can you? All I am saying is that $|b|<|a|$ only gets you that far.

Comment: No it is not. You are confused. You put an absolute value, the only conclusion you get is absolute convergence because you had to put an absolute value to do comparison (only works for series of definite sign).

Comment: The extra information that you are missing is that outside of the interval resulting from comparing to a geometric series, the general term doesn't tend to zero and therefore the original series diverges. It is a small detail that students tend to forget. Otherwise all information you have is about the set of points of absolute convergence.

Comment: OK. You are just obfuscated and very wrong. Just think this, if you were right, then your argument would work for all series in which the absolute value of the general term is monotonic with respect to the variable. And that is very much not true. So far all you have done is prove that the set of absolute convergence is an interval. Comparison only gets you that far.

Comment: @yixing I'm not convinced that you're actually reading my comments, giving the rapidity of your replies. Here is the extremely brief argument: Let $a$ be a point where the series converges (conditionally *or* absolutely). Then the series converges absolutely on $[0, a)$ and converges on $\{a\}$; hence the series converges on $[0, a]$. As an immediate consequence, the set $\{x : \text{ the series converges}\}$ is convex. Hence the set is an interval. If you can identify an error in this logic, I'd be happy to know about it. But I don't think you will.

Comment: Look at your very last comment and now look at your answer. See how your comment claims that from convergence (not necessarily absolute) at $a$ (therefore you are not allowed to put $|a|$ or get infinite sums) you get convergence at $|b|<|a|$? Now look at your answer and see the $|a|$. You really need to review your power series. That's it.

Comment: One cannot give a counterexample for a wrong proof of a correct result. Only point out the erroneous argument. And what I said is real, you do need to look at the actual proof such that you really understand it.

Comment: Move on. It is you who loses learning something so basic. Just try to prove the very claim that you are making in the comment. You will see that what you wrote in the answer will never get you there. From your research area I know that at least you are not one of my students. So, it doesn't affect me.